# how to use wifi on ubuntu 16.04 instaled over vm ware workstation pro 12 in windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox-networking

i am new to ubuntu 16.04
i am not able to see any wifi option in ubuntu.
i googled and tried to find the solution.
on using`ifconfig` command it shows only ethernet and lo. 
how to use wifi on this ubuntu virtual machine.
I can access internet if i connect wifi in windows and then connect to wired connection in ubuntu. 
i installed ubuntu 16.04 in parallel with win 8.1 on another laptop but problem is same. There is no wifi option there.

Answer (score 0):

In Virtual Machine you can not use WiFi. I think this is for safty reason but I an not sure. If you realy want to have WiFi in VM there is possibility to connect external wifi card to VM.

Now..if you installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot next to Win 8.1 and there is still no wifi than thare is also a problem with ubuntu not detecting your wifi card on that laptop.